# Stuck on thread, giving up - Android

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I have a `run-method` inside my class that extends `Thread`. Codesnipp:

```
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        Log.i("INSIDE RUN: ", "STARTING LISTNING FOR INPUTSTREAM" ); 
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected

        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                //Log.d("BYTES FROM THE DEVICE: ", Integer.toString(bytes));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

After some time LogCat gives me the following error:

```
07-27 14:51:55.860: E/dalvikvm(17271): threadid=2: stuck on threadid=1187, giving up
```

I assume that what this error message is trying to tell me, is that the thread is going in a `spinlock` and doing `Busy waiting`, in terms of OS related stuff. But why do a Busy waiting, I am actualy doing something, reading streams. Can anybody pinpoint me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Probably there is no data coming on that stream?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29 . Interesting part is: `This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.`

Comment: Thanks bicska88. The inputstream should be available, because I managed to do so with the inbuilt android bluetooth service. But the data that I recieve is a binary object, the device is using OBEX object push profile to send files. I assume that its this causing the problem, no "translatation for OBEX"

Comment: I'd use a `Service` instead of an old `Thread` to do this.